# How to get date picker value in cypress

Tags: angular, testing, datepicker, cypress

[image]

I am doing some E2E test using cypress and I want to get the date that appears on a DatePicker element from my  app. I tried this but both return an empty string:

```js
export class SettingPage {
  doc_expirydate='#txtDocExpiryDate'

  clickexpirydate (date) { 
    cy.get(this.doc_expirydate).type(date) 
  }

}
```

```js
import { SettingPage } from "./Pages/setting_page"`
const settingpage = new SettingPage()

it('Setting_Page', function () {

  settingpage.clickexpirydate('type=date','2023-01-07')

}
```

[image]

I want to enter the date to complete E2E testing.

Comment: Please edit your question and convert the images to code fragments in the question. That makes it easier to read your question and cut and paste your code. Also, try to correct the formatting of the code that is in your question.

Answer (score 3):

The call to the `clickexpirydate()` method has two parameters, but the method only receives one parameter.

Change it to this

```js
settingpage.clickexpirydate('2023-01-07')
```